# SVN using wrong path for txn-current-lock

Tags: svn

I have checked out a local copy of an SVN repository, using `svn checkout https://svn.foo.com/Foo`, into a directory `/home/myusername/dir/subdir/Foo/Foo-svn/`.  When I try to commit to the repository, I get this error:

`svn: E000013: Can't open file '/home/foo/webapps/com_foo_svn/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied`

I don't know where it's coming up with that file path.  The directory `/home/foo/` doesn't even exist.

I haven't really used Subversion before, and I don't know where it keeps configuration things like that.  All the other StackOverflow references I've found to this error seem to be cases where the file path is correct and the permissions are just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is using the correct path.

The error comes from the server, not from the client. The path `/home/foo/webapps/com_foo_svn/db/txn-current-lock` is located on the server side. Therefore, you should **check the permissions on the server**.